# How to simplify my java code function?

Tags: java

How to make this code simplified? I'm having doubt on having two switch statements in my function.

```
    private String getKeyword(String id) {
    String keyword = "";
    switch (id.substring(1, 2)) {
        case "E":
            keyword = "英語";
            break;
        case "M":
            keyword = "数学";
            break;
        case "W":
            keyword = "統合";
            break;
    }
    switch (id.substring(4,5)){
        case "W":
            keyword = "統合";
            break;
    }
    return keyword;
}
```

Comment: This question is off-topic here. You may ask such questions on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A switch statement with one case doesn't make sense. You can just do `if (id.substring(4,5).equals("W")) { keyword = "統合"; }`

Comment: If you only want to map a substring to a keyword you might use a `Map` (surprising name ;-) ). Have a look at the [collections tutorial chapter Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private String getKeyword(String id) {
    String keyword = "";
    switch (id.substring(1, 2)) {
        case "E":
            keyword = "英語";
            break;
        case "M":
            keyword = "数学";
            break;
        case "W":
            keyword = "統合";
            break;
    }
    if ("W".equals(id.substring(4, 5))) keyword = "統合";
    return keyword;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use just `if else if` statements.
It would be less verbose.

Besides, the before last and the last condition have similarities.
So you could put them in a single statement by combining them with an OR operator.
 Both return `"統合"`.

At last, you could return directly the value instead of valuing a local variable in each matched case.
But as the second switch statement overwrites the value to return, 
you should move it as the first condition to test.
 It would make things much clearer :

```
private String getKeyword(String id) {

     char c  = id.substring(1, 2).charAt(0);

     if (c == 'W' || id.substring(4,5).charAt(0) ==  'W'){
        return "統合";
     }  
     else if (c == 'E'){
        return "英語";
     } 
     else if (c == 'M'){
        return "数学";
     }                    

     return "";
}
```

Comment: You should return `"統合"` when `id = "xExxW"`.

Comment: @saka1029 Good catch. Thanks a lot. I updated consequently.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Enumeration.
Each of them would contain one or multiple id and the corresponding keyword: easier to read and maintain.
Finally, declare a static method in the Enumeration to retrieve the expected element depending on a provided id.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a keyword map and use it instead. As this is static, you can make this map an instance variable and just use it when that method is called.

```
//do this in something like a constructor
Map<String, String> keywordMap = new HashMap<>;
keywordMap.put("E", "英語");
//more put calls

//and in your method, you'll only need
return keywordMap.get(id.substring(1, 2));
```

Pay attention to the logic implemented using two `switch`. As matches in the first switch don't cause the method to return, matches in the second switch can overwrite the keyword variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a map:

```
private static final Map<String, String> letterToKeyword =
    Map.of("E", "英語", "M", "数学", "W", "統合");

private String getKeyword(String id) {
    if (id.substring(4,5).equals("W")) return "統合";
    return letterToKeyword.getOrDefault(id.substring(1, 2), "");
}
```

Prior to Java 9 building the map would be a little more verbose (but could be assisted with a helper method, if so desired):

```
private static final Map<String, String> letterToKeyword;

static {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("E", "英語");
    map.put("M", "数学");
    map.put("W", "統合");
    letterToKeyword = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the body of the switches in separately functions.

you could also remove the break's and return instantly in the cases, if you want it shorter.

You could also use enums

One of your switches can be replaced by a simple if statement.

```
private String getKeyword(String id) 
{
    if(id.substring(4,5).equals("W"))
    {
        return "統合";
    }
    else
    {
        switch (id.substring(1, 2)) {
            case "E":
                return "英語";
            case "M":
                return "数学";
            case "W":
                return "統合";
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```